# ¿Como puedo Salvar una Factura creada en VBA directamente en PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

¿Como puedo Salvar una Factura creada en VBA directamente en PDF, después de darle al botón imprimir?

saludos tengo una Factura  creada en Excel VBA con macros y me gustaría grabar esa misma forma como formato pdf pero la función .saveas no me funciona ni tampoco la función de activesheet.

la activesheet solo funciona para hojas seleccionada en Excel y no es lo que quiero guardar.
para grabar estaba usando la función .printout, pero al conectar la impresora solo me imprime y no me guarda el archivo.
que puedo hacer?

[image: esta es la forma a guardar]

e escrito abajo la forma en la que estoy trabajando en VBA ,espero se pueda entender y haya desarrollado la pregunta adecuadamente para  ayuda.

```css
Private Sub Bt_Imprimir_Click()
 'FileCopy( Factura-" & Me.txt_NumeroFactura.Value & ".PDF" ; "C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Confianza Macros\FACTURA\" )
 'RegistrodeFactura.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 'Filename:="C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Confianza Macros\FACTURA\Factura-" & _
 'Me.txt_NumeroFactura.Value & ".", Quality:=xlQualityStandard
 
 '
 'Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 'Filename:="C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Confianza Macros\FACTURA\Factura-" & _
 'Me.txt_NumeroFactura.Value & ".", Quality:=xlQualityStandard

 
    With RegistrodeFactura
    .PrintForm
    .Save Filename:="C:\Users\Amanda\Downloads\Confianza Macros\FACTURA\Factura-" & _
 Me.txt_NumeroFactura.Value & ".PDF" 'esta intruccion es para imprimir una copia
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola Noemi, bienvenida, el código debe ir como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines la imagen que lo contiene y lo agregues como texto,  así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: ¿Qué clase de objeto es `RegistrodeFactura`? La clase `Form` tiene el método `Printform` que te lo puede enviar a una impresora de PDF si es la predeterminada. Pero no tiene el método `Save` como tal. No puedes salvar un formulario directamente a PDF pero sí puedes enviarlo a una impresora PDF.